# Getting charts.js to read from Google Sheet JSON data

Tags: json, chart.js

I have hard coded charts online using charts.js as follows:

```
var config = {
type: 'pie',
data: {
    datasets: [{
        data: [2574,1663,1670],
        backgroundColor: [window.chartColors.red,window.chartColors.green,window.chartColors.blue],
        label: 'Dataset 1'
    }],
    labels: ['Label1','Label2','Label3']
},
options: {
    responsive: true,
    legend: { display: false }
}
};
```

I am trying to change the data source to a Google Sheet. For this, I use:

```
$.getJSON("https://cors.io?https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1OAYVJjSUqHdCwcdLSEaENQML8JwK6IwWbFFUkU1PGms/1/public/values?alt=json", function(data) {
});
```

Next, I fetch data from row1/columnA (named 'charts') and get the value like this:

```
data.feed.entry[0]['gsx$charts']['$t'];
```

Where gsx$charts is the column name and entry[0] is the first row of data. This all works well if I were to, for example:

```
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
$.getJSON("https://cors.io?https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1OAYVJjSUqHdCwcdLSEaENQML8JwK6IwWbFFUkU1PGms/1/public/values?alt=json", function(data) {
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = data.feed.entry[0]['gsx$charts']['$t'];
});
</script>
```

This will print the value to screen correctly.

Now I'm trying to get charts.js to make use the data for labels and chart data. I'm not certain how to approach this.

Examples that don't work:

```
labels: [
    'data.feed.entry[0]['gsx$charts']['$t'];',
    'data.feed.entry[1]['gsx$charts']['$t'];',
    'data.feed.entry[2]['gsx$charts']['$t'];'
]

labels: [
    data.feed.entry[0]['gsx$charts']['$t'];,
    data.feed.entry[1]['gsx$charts']['$t'];,
    data.feed.entry[2]['gsx$charts']['$t'];
]

labels: [
    data.feed.entry[0]['gsx$charts']['$t'],
    data.feed.entry[1]['gsx$charts']['$t'],
    data.feed.entry[2]['gsx$charts']['$t']
]
```

In most cases, the chart fails to load or actually renders the data.feed code as the text labels.

The Google Sheet has hundreds of rows and several columns with unique labels and data. I call a specific row or column like this:

```
// Read 'charts' column, row 1 (0 is actually the first row)
data.feed.entry[0]['gsx$charts']['$t'];'
// Read 'charts' column, row 2
data.feed.entry[1]['gsx$charts']['$t'];'
// Read 'charts' column, row 33
data.feed.entry[32]['gsx$charts']['$t'];'
// Read 'titles' column, row 24
data.feed.entry[23]['gsx$titles']['$t'];'
// and so on
```

Just can't seem to figure out how to get the charts.js syntax to read the values. Thoughts appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array values must be separated by commas.

```
labels: [
    data.feed.entry[0]["gsx$charts"]["$t"],
    data.feed.entry[1]["gsx$charts"]["$t"],
    data.feed.entry[2]["gsx$charts"]["$t"]
]
```

See this implementation:

```js
(function() {
  window.chartColors = {
    red: "rgb(255, 99, 132)",
    green: "rgb(75, 192, 192)",
    blue: "rgb(54, 162, 235)"
  };
  $.getJSON("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1OAYVJjSUqHdCwcdLSEaENQML8JwK6IwWbFFUkU1PGms/1/public/values?alt=json", function(data) {
    var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
    window.myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: "pie",
      data: {
        datasets: [{
          data: [2574, 1663, 1670],
          backgroundColor: [window.chartColors.red, window.chartColors.green, window.chartColors.blue],
          label: "Dataset 1"
        }],
        labels: [
          data.feed.entry[0]["gsx$charts"]["$t"],
          data.feed.entry[1]["gsx$charts"]["$t"],
          data.feed.entry[2]["gsx$charts"]["$t"]
        ]
      },
      options: {
        responsive: true
      }
    });
  });
}());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.chartjs.org/dist/2.7.2/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="width: 75%;">
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```